# How to find the first lattice point in the first quadrant on the line $21x-101y=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

How to find the first lattice point in the first quadrant on the line $21x-101y=1$?

I can find the lattice point with the help of modular arithmetic. But is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: Use the extended euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&\text{$x$ is an integer such that $21x - 101y = 1$, for some integer $y$}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&21x \equiv  1\;(\text{mod}\;101)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&105x \equiv  5\;(\text{mod}\;101)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&4x \equiv  5\;(\text{mod}\;101)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&100x \equiv 125\;(\text{mod}\;101)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&-x \equiv 24\;\;(\text{mod}\;101)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x \equiv -24\;\;(\text{mod}\;101)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x \equiv 77\;\;(\text{mod}\;101)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x = 77+101k,\;\text{for some integer $k$}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that the smallest nonnegative qualifying value of $x$ is $77$.

Plugging $x=77$ into the equation $21x-101y=1$ yields $y=16$, so the required point is $(x,y) = (77,16)$.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer! Is there another way of finding that point? Euclidean algorithm can also be used but I am looking for any other way to the solution such as intersection of two lines kind of approach.

Comment: Perhaps, but congruences is the way I would do it, and, if the coefficients are small, you can easily find an ad-hoc solution, without invoking the machinery of the extended  Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{r|rrr}
 \text{multiplier} &   x &  y & 21x - 101y\\
\hline
                   &   0 & -1 & 101\\
               -5  &   1 &  0 & 21\\
\hline
                5  &  -5 & -1 & -4\\
                   & -24 & -5 & 1\\
\hline
\end{array}

The scheme above is next row = multiplier times current row plus previous row.

So an integer solution to $21x - 101y = 1$ is $(x,y)=(-24,-5)$

A general solution is $(x,y) = (-24+101t, -5+21t)$

Since $x > 0 \implies t \ge 1$ and $y > 0 \implies t \ge 1$, then the first integer solution to occur in the first quadrant happens when $t=1$. We get

$$(x,y) = (77,16)$$

Comment: Thanks for your technique please let me know how do you determine the multiplier.

Comment: Choose the multiplier in such a way that the number is the last column is as small as possible. Ultimately, you want a 1 in the last column. BTW, if you get a -1 in the last column, say {24, 5, -1}, then add one more row with all of the signs changed {-24, -5, 1}.